# AWS PinPoint - SMS Message From Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to initiate a SMS message using Postman, but I keep getting a response indicating "Invalid Request Body". I can't seem to find a good example on the AWS documentation (Is it just me or does anyone else encounter this with AWS?)

Below is the request body I'm submitting with my request. Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
{
    "ApplicationId": "<MyApplicationID>",
      "MessageRequest": {
        "Addresses": {
          "[{{Destination}}]": {
            "BodyOverride": "Test",
            "ChannelType": "SMS"
          }
    },
        "MessageConfiguration": {
            "SMSMessage": {
                "Body": "Test",
                "SenderId": "Test",
                "MessageType": "TRANSACTIONAL",
                "Keyword": "<MyKeyword>",
                "OriginationNumber": "<Origination number in E.164 Format>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Amazon Pinpoint [**SendMessages**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-messages.html#apps-application-id-messages-request-examples) REST API, the request body doesn't include either the **application-id** key or **MessageRequest** key.

**Resolution:**

You will need to put the Amazon Pinpoint **application-id** in the URI part (or create an environmental variable) and then specify the request body as shown below **:**

[image: Amazon Pinpoint SendMessages using POSTMAN]

Hope this helps!